# Setting up Django and Posgtresql on ubuntu

Tags: python, postgresql, django

I am running Kubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have been reading the django book and I have hit a snag where I'm unable to set up posgresql to work with the django app.

I have installed both  python-postgresql and python-psycopg via synaptic. When I run: `import conncetion from django.db`  I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                          
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>                                                 
    if settings.DATABASES and DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__                                            
    self._setup(name)                                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in _setup                                                 
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))                                                                                                         
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the envirogs.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Help me understand how django and postgreql communicate or direct me to a django tutorial suited for beginners or a post that helps one set up django and posgre on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide details in `settings.py`. This is the part which you have to configure

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Please refer http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html#configuring-the-database

**EDIT:**

This is your `settings.py` file with out the comments.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
        'NAME': 'blank_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'thepasswd',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

You are missing a comma at the end of `ENGINE` entry

Comment: I think it's looking for settings.py in the wrong place. I have my databases part well configured. here it is: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3l4n8Q6GpBOS0VZRTRJdjFOczg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your folder structure?

Comment: The one you get when you run `django-admin.py startproject mysite.`. If I uninstalled and re-isntalled django would that fix it?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check that

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. That comma was an issue though. I have a feeling it's looking for the settings.py in the wrong place. All I am doing is opening the shell entering `python` and then entering `import django.db`.

Comment: You are right. You shouldnt be doing that. Create a new .py file and edit it with an editor.

Comment: what should be in the new.py file? I cd'd into djcode code where there is manage.py and ran `python` then I ran `from django.db import connection` and then `cursor = connection.cursor`. All without errors. So I assume it worked. The key was to work from the directory with manage.py file. Thanks that helped.